# Is there a DTD or XSD for Ivy 1.0 XML files?

Tags: java, xml, build, ivy

I was wondering if there was a DTD or XSD for 1.0 XML files. It is one of the warnings in my IDE and I would rather add a DTD/XSD to the XML then to set my IDE to ignore it.

I am asking specifically for version 1+ and not 2.0 for the file with the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivy 1.0 was released in 2005, and it got updated to 1.1 after two months. It does seem a bit peculiar you'd need exactly 1.0 and not anything more recent.

The oldest web archive can find is the [version from 2007](http://web.archive.org/web/20071018075809/http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd), which could be, based on a guess by date, the 1.4. version. For a schema older than that you might want to ask directly from their [mailing list](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/mailing-lists.html).

Comment: Well I meant for a version earlier than 2.0 . I just wanted to make sure that the schema was compatible with the version we are using at work and it is a really old version (while maybe not actually 1.0 the jar is labelled as such).